# Combine reference citations

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I would like the reference citation to appear like [1-4], rather than [1], [2], [3], [4].

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\begin{document}

 Some text

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}   
\bibliography{refer}    
\end{document}
```

How to solve this pooling of citations?

Comment: To achieve this with biblatex you can use the style `numeric-comp`.

Comment: use donald arseneau's cite.sty to do this with minimum effort;  natbib.sty "sort+compress" option also does the job.  see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=citesort

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use the `style=numeric-comp` for [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Here is the output from the [`numeric-comp.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/31-style-numeric-comp.tex) example file (without loading [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), for clarity):

[image: Loading biblatex with style numeric-comp]

The output is similar to that provided by the [`cite` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite).

Comment: I am using \bibliographystyle{unsrt} in my article to generate the references as they appear. but, if i use the one use have prescribed, i am not getting the references as they appear.

Comment: @Anil: In your document preamble you should use `\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}\addbibresource{refer.bib}` and then only `\printbibliography` where you want the references printed in your document. `\bibliographystyle` is not used with `biblatex`.

Comment: in that case, references will be cited as per the entry in .bib file and not as they appear in the manuscript.

Comment: @Anil: As mentioned in my answer, you may be interested in the [`cite` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) then, rather than [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: I tried this and still doesnot work. I have entered my manuscript like this.    \cite{ref1},    \cite{ref3}, and    \cite{ref2}. But still references appear like [1], [2] and [3]. How to edit the tex file?

Comment: @Anil: What about `\cite{ref1,ref2,ref3}`?