# Multiple references

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have several references like `\cite{a,b,c,d,e}` which produces an output like
`[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]`.

Is there a way to automatically generate the above as `[1]-[5]`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Use the style `numeric-comp`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine reference citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43563/combine-reference-citations)

Comment: @Werner: Not really ;-) [1]-[5] isn't the default output of numeric-comp. Of course you can use it as a basic.

Comment: @Werner: It seems the OP uses `numeric-verb` and wants to combine its features and that of `numeric-comp`.

Comment: @lockstep: How do you guess `numeric verb`.

Comment: Can someone please give a sample of how to use these packages and use the statements?

Comment: @Bill: You are using `biblatex`. What do you mean?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel `\cite` produces exactly the results described by the OP with `numeric-verb`.

Comment: @lockstep: I changed my answer ;-)

Comment: `\usepackage{biblatex}`
`\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}` When I use this I get error saying biblatex.bib not found

Comment: @Bill: I provided an example. You can't load biblatex twice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on your rudimentary information I *guess* you are using the style `numeric-verb` (Thanks lockstep). First of all I recommend to use the style `numeric-comp` which has the following output as default:

> [1-5]

To obtain this output, see [Combine reference citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43563/combine-reference-citations). However it seems that you request the format

> [1]-[5]

This is also possible by a modification of the command `\cite`:

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {%
   \renewrobustcmd*{\bibrangedash}{\bibclosebracket\textendash\bibopenbracket}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\cite{companion,knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\parencite{companion,knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compile with

```
(pdf)latex
biber
(pdf)latex
(pdf)latex
```

[image]