# Multiple cites separated by a line

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, thesis

a summary of my code would be what follows

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah \cite{ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref10}
\end{document}
```

With this code, I end up with something like this

**blah blah blah [1,2,3,4,10]**

However, I would like a more compact notation like

**blah blah blah [1-4, 10]**

How should I edit the prelude in order to achieve that? I have looked it up but haven't found an answer

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `numeric-comp` style: `\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3871/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43563/35864

Comment: @moewe Really useful, thank you!